# Can't get lm-sensors to ouput correctly or load ATI Radeon temp and fan

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, ati, fglrx, sensors

I am new to Linux and having minor issues. I followed [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2780) initially, but did not receive the proper output, and it did not show my ATI Radeon HD 5000 temperature or fan speed. Then I used [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto), and the same problems were exhibited. I had no 
issues installing it and no errors. I think it's not reading `i2c` for some reason. The proprietary driver is installed and functioning correctly according to `fglrxinfo`. I can use `aticonfig` commands and view both the temperature and fan. Thoughts?

Any ideas on how to get it working under `sensors`?

When I run `sudo sensors-detect` this is my output

```
# sensors-detect revision 5984 (2011-07-10 21:22:53 +0200)
# System: LENOVO IdeaPad Y560 (laptop)
# Board: Lenovo KL3

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8502
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel 3400/5 Series (PCH)

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

My output for `sensors` is:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +58.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

and my `/etc/modules` is:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc

# Generated by sensors-detect on Fri Nov 30 23:24:31 2012
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, lm-sensors can't read the fglrx fan and temperature, the module only support the reading of this values via the `aticonfig` with command like this:

```
aticonfig --pplib-cmd "get temperature 0"
aticonfig --od-gettemperature
```

Comment: Yep; if you want lm-sensors to be able to read it you need to use the open source driver instead of fglrx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed i2c-devel or i2c-tools? If not, install one or the other, whichever is available in your distribution's repositories, reboot, then try sensors-detect again. If it still doesn't work, try the open source drivers that come with your distribution, reboot, and try again.

P.S.: When you post a question, proper form is to state your computer's hardware in full (not just one component of it), and the specific OS you are on (Mageia? Arch? Fedora? Windows? What? What version of it? I understand this to be Ubuntu, but which version?), the exact driver you are on for the problem you are having (which file installed it? Where did you get it?), and what exactly you have tried so far to get things to work for you.

http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html